# What causes an infinite loop of errors when translating this google-maps component from class-based to functional?

Tags: react-native, google-maps

I work with maps a lot, and was hoping to improve [this](https://medium.com/@pallavi8khedle/google-map-integration-with-react-native-expo-mobile-and-web-348a920c84c0) solution by translating it to functional way. However, no polyline is visible, and the browser console spits out an endless stream of 403s:

```
  GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=33.843663,-117.945171&waypoints=33.8589565,-117.9589782&destination=33.8252956,-117.8307728&key=AIzaSyDo6JaxjeTpLTgZeU-kxb0s3z3_SG0Be6Y 403 (Forbidden)
(anonymous) @ GetCoords.js:68
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
fetchRouteData @ GetCoords.js:59
(anonymous) @ MapScreen.js:101
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
fetchData @ MapScreen.js:93
(anonymous) @ MapScreen.js:109
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

Minimal reproducible example is [HERE](https://github.com/ydrea/geolocation).

Comment: Have you tried just going to that URL with your browser? https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=33.843663,-117.945171&waypoints=33.8589565,-117.9589782&destination=33.8252956,-117.8307728&key=AIzaSyDo6JaxjeTpLTgZeU-kxb0s3z3_SG0Be6Y

Comment: I see:
Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with